# Seaching for duplicate customers with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find duplicate customers in a table that looks like this:

```
customer_id | first_name | last_name 
-------------------------------------
          0 | Rich       | Smith
          1 | Paul       | Jones
          2 | Richard    | Smith
          3 | Jimmy      | Roberts
```

In this situation, I need a query that will return with customer_id 0 and customer_id 2. The query needs to find matches where a customer may have shortened their name, Rich instead of Richard -- or Rob instead of Robert.

I have this query but it's only returning ONE (not both) of the matches. I need both Rich & Richard returned by the query.

```
select distinct customers.customer_id, concat(customers.first_name,' ',customers.last_name) as name from customers
inner join customers dup on customers.last_name = dup.last_name
where (dup.first_name like concat('%', customers.first_name, '%')
and dup.customer_id <> customers.customer_id )
order by name
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Per @tsOverflow , this is the final query that solved my problem:

```
select distinct customers.customer_id, concat(customers.first_name,' ',customers.last_name) as name 
from customers
    inner join customers dup on customers.last_name = dup.last_name
where ((dup.first_name like concat('%', customers.first_name, '%') 
            OR (customers.first_name like concat('%', dup.first_name, '%')) 
        )
    and dup.customer_id <> customers.customer_id )
order by name
```

The above solution may have performance issues.

Comment: How do you expect MySQL to stem the name 'Richard' to 'Rich'?

Comment: You will need secondary information to solve the problem.  Depending on the person entering the information you could get: `Mike` = `Mike` or `Mike` = `Michael` and `Jo` = `Joseph` and `Jo` = `Joann` and on the same note: Why is `Rich Smith` = `Richard Smith`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because Rich is a substring of Richard, but not the other way around.

This will check for both ways:

```
select distinct randomtest.customer_id, concat(randomtest.first_name,' ',randomtest.last_name) as name 
from randomtest
    inner join randomtest dup on randomtest.last_name = dup.last_name
where ((dup.first_name like concat('%', randomtest.first_name, '%') 
            OR (randomtest.first_name like concat('%', dup.first_name, '%')) 
        )
    and dup.customer_id <> randomtest.customer_id )
order by name
```

I added the OR and do the like check the other way around.
Note that using like statement in query has performance implcations - I am not expert in this, just a thought.

EDIT:
As others mentioned on comment - this will only catch cases where the "shorten" version is really just a substring, it wont catch cases where Michael -> Mike, or William -> Bill, and on the other hand John and some guy named Johnson might be 2 totaly different people too.

Comment: This did it. For posterity, I'll add the final query to the question above. 

Thanks for the help! This had me pretty stumped.

Comment: You should add the query to your original post as an update so it's easier to read. @tsOverflow: Not just the like, but the OR will impact performance as well.

Comment: Per your edit -- in this case, that is preferable. The users are presented with a list of "possible duplicates" and can choose to merge customer data after comparing the two of them. 

It's a unique situation so this solution may not fit others needs, but it's exactly what I needed. Thanks again!